# Reported/Indirect Speech and Past Simple with when. Can they get confused with each other?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past, indirect-speech

Going straight to the point, let's say that I have a sentence like

> He asked when the train arrived.

How can I tell whether this is a Past Simple (As soon as the train arrived he asked) or Reported Speech (He: "When does the train arrive?"). Is there a way to distinguish between them? Or maybe I'm doing some other mistake that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It wouldn't be reported speech for "When does the train arrive?" (That would be "He asked when the train would arrive") but could be for "When did the train arrive?" Since the latter is less common, it reduces the ambiguity.

Comment: I always thought that when we use reported speech we "move" one tense back. So we would end up with something like:
- "When does the train arrive?" - Regular action, train is on a schedule - we "move" one to the past and get - "He asked when the train arrived".
- "When will the train arrive?" - One time question, not related to the schedule - "He asked when the train would arrive".

Comment: @BartłomiejVarilKręgielewski: yes, I agree. I was writing something similar in my answre below at the same  time as you wrote this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Without context, these are equally possible interpretations: you have a structural ambiguity.

In context, it will usually be clear, because *ask* is normally transitive, and only if the object (the question or request) is already in the discourse will it be used intransitively. So in

> He asked me if I had seen her. He asked when the train arrived.

*when the train arrived* is an adverbial phrase, but in

> He asked when the train arrived.

without context, it is an indirect question.

There is another point though: though the past simple is grammatical here, I think it is likely only because he is talking about something timetabled, like a train. So if he asked

> When does the train arrive?

meaning "What time is the train scheduled to arrive?" then you might say

> He asked when the train arrived.

But if he asked about an individual particular event, such as:

> When do you go?

then to my ears

> He asked when I went.

is unclear, and I'd be much more likely to say

> He asked when I was going.